# Using tempfiles for intermediate dataset in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-2.7, in-memory

I want to create a simple python arcpy script for ArcGIS.

Because in my script I have to many raster and shp where I need only to take 
final result I try to use tempfiles for this unusually datasets. 
I have read this [post](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/using-the-in-memory-output-workspace.htm) for `in_memory` files and I try

This snippet :

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
# Local variables:
dem_tif = "C:/Users/my/path/dem.tif"
slope = "in_memory/slope.tif"
rastertopoint_shp = "in_memory/points.shp"
# Process: Slope
arcpy.gp.Slope_sa(dem_tif, slope, "DEGREE", "1")
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(slope1, rastertopoint_shp, "Value")
..................................................................
```

But I take this error :

```
arcpy.gp.Slope_sa(dem_tif, slope, "DEGREE", "1")
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 001167: No extension is allowed for in-memory raster dataset name
Failed to execute (Slope).
```

How can I work with Python tempfiles in arcpy for intermediate files ?

Comment: Remove .tif: `"in_memory/slope"`

Comment: The ArcGIS  `in_memory` workspace should not be confused with a "temporary file" model. It really is memory-based, with no suffixes permitted on table names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cant have a file extension for rasters in the in_memory workspace so change `slope = "in_memory/slope.tif"` to `slope = "in_memory/slope`"

See: 
[001167: No extension is allowed for in-memory raster dataset name.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01151-01175-001167.htm)

If you want to save the in_memory raster on disk (for example as *.tif) use [Copy Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm):

> Saves a copy of a raster dataset or converts a mosaic dataset into a
>   single raster dataset.